# Specify proxy in asp.net core rc2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, coreclr

I'm trying to specify the web proxy for a request using WebAPI in a dotnet core app. This block of code used to work when I targeted the actual clr (dnx46) but, now I'm trying to use the rc2 stuff that says the supported frameworks are netcoreapp1.0 and netstandard1.5.

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler{
    Proxy = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._clientSettings.ProxyUrl) ? null : new WebProxy (this._clientSettings.ProxyUrl, this._clientSettings.BypassProxyOnLocal),
    UseProxy = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._clientSettings.ProxyUrl)
};
```

I'm wondering where WebProxy class went. I can't find it anywhere, not even in the github repositories. If it changed from WebProxy, what did it change to?
I need to be able to set the proxy to a specific url for specific requests, so using the "global Internet Explorer" way of things isn't going to work for my needs. This is mostly for debugging of web requests/response purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue today. Turns out that we have to provide our own implementation of `IWebProxy`. Fortunately it's not complicated at all:

```
public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
{
    public MyProxy(string proxyUri)
        : this(new Uri(proxyUri))
    {
    }

    public MyProxy(Uri proxyUri)
    {
        this.ProxyUri = proxyUri;
    }

    public Uri ProxyUri { get; set; }

    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        return this.ProxyUri;
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        return false; /* Proxy all requests */
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
var config = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseProxy = true,
    Proxy = new MyProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8118")
};

using (var http = new HttpClient(config))
{
    var ip = http.GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org/").Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Your IP: {0}");
}
```

And in your particular situation you could even put the logic determining if a proxy is required inside your IWebProxy implementation.

Comment: I've faced similar issue but with one difference. I need to use default system proxy. However for .net framework setting proxy to null does work. Please correct if i'm wrong.

Comment: How make .net core to use default system proxy?